# Are there any C# facial recognition libraries that work?

Tags: c#, search

Are there any C# facial recognition libraries that work? I would like to locate people in my data base by having them stare in a camera :-). This is not used for security or authentication just to help with a quick lookup so if it is good enough to narrow down a list of people that would be a win.

Comment: i was going to suggest opencv but it doesn't look as though it supports c#

Comment: See my answer below; emgu cv is a C# wrapper for opencv, and quite good in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into Microsoft's Face API:

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api/documentation/overview

Comment: This is best one

Comment: This is why I ended up here. First, find an offline detection library, if face is found, then send it to Azure. Saves me transactions per month!

Comment: @DannyThunder Which offline detection library you have used. I want to do the same